# How is choice made between coronary angioplasty and coronary artery bypass surgery

Tags: heart-disease, angioplasty, cabg-coronary-art-bypass

Coronary angioplasty (PTCA or PCI with stenting) and coronary artery bypass surgery (CABG) are 2 main methods to treat severe symptomatic coronary artery disease.

Former is done through tiny catheters under X-ray fluoroscopy with patient in awake state while latter is a proper open chest surgical procedure with patient under anesthesia.

How is choice made between PTCA/PCI and CABG?

Comment: You can search for "indications" and "contraindications" for both interventions. They can include multiple narrowings of a single coronary artery, patient's age, overall health, etc.

Comment: What are the results of your own research so far?